# Add a class to a specific sibling element, not every single sibling that appears on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this function that adds a class to a sibling element inside the main parent.

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
    if ($('#Correct').css('display') == 'block'){
            $('div[data-answer="1"]').addClass('test-class'); 
        } else {
    }
});
```

When this executes, it adds a class to any div that has this attribute because the same code appears several times on the page:

```
[data-answer="1"]
```

I was wondering if it was possible to add the class only to its sibling div with that data attribute, without adding a class to all of them on the page? If that makes any sense at all? I'm new to javascript so please bear with me.

Comment: sibling of what, `#Correct` element? How many `#Correct` elements can be there in the page?

Comment: It would help tremendously to see what your HTML looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Use siblings() function of jquery

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
    if ($('#Correct').css('display') == 'block'){
          $('#Correct').siblings('div[data-answer="1"]').addClass('test-class'); 
    } else {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .find() and .first() to get the first matching element only.

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
if ($('#Correct').css('display') == 'block'){
        $('#Correct').find('div[data-answer="1"]').first().addClass('test-class'); 
    } else {
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks Osama, I've managed to get this part working. It will work beautifully on the first click for the first element but when i move to the next question it doesn't change. Would you know how to make it work for other instances of the same code with each click?

Comment: That is because you are using ID as a selector ('#Correct'). Since ID is unique, it always targets the same element on your page. 
It would be helpful if you post the HTML part as well for better suggestions :)